# How to add group access to SVN+LDAP access?

Tags: svn, apache

I have a system already set up using ldap to control access to svn repos.

Currently ldap users can get FULL access to the repository.

What I want to achieve:
set up 2 groups in ldap for one svn repository:

- project_developer
- project_guest

where

- project_developer have read and write access
- project_guest have read only access.

Is there anyone know how to make this work? or any hint would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Environment

- CentOS release 4.9 (Final)
- Apache 2
- Subversion version 1.4.6 (r28521)

Comment: You may find better answers by asking this question on servfail.  I'd also emphasise what other technologies are involved.  e.g. linux/windows, IIS/Apache.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,I'll add my environments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Location />
      AuthBasicProvider ldap
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "SVN Server"
      #general user for ldap requests which password never expire
      AuthLDAPBindDN insertLdapUserHere
      AuthLDAPBindPassword insertPasswordForLdapUserHere
      AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldapServerHostName.companyXYZ.com:3268/?userPrincipalName?sub?(objectClass=user)
      Require valid-user

    </Location>
    <Location /path/to/repo/which/apear/in/webbrowser>

      # Uncomment this to enable the repository
      DAV svn

      # Set this to the path to your repository
      SVNPath /absolute/path/to/the/repo

      #set order of authentification
      Order Deny,Allow
      #generally disallow for all
      Deny from all
      #only allow for Germany and Amerika
      Allow from GER.companyXYZ.com US.companyXYZ.com
      # allow read and write access to ldap modify group
      # IMPROTANT: User full qualified name for group
      Require ldap-group CN=Modiy-GroupName,OU=Groups,OU=DomainName,DC=companyXYZ,DC=com
      # for read request allow all users in the read group
      # Limit handle only the read access commands, if such a command will be received, it checks the Read-Group
      <Limit OPTIONS PROPFIND GET REPORT>
        Require ldap-group CN=Read-GroupName,OU=Groups,OU=DomainName,DC=companyXYZ,DC=com
      </Limit>
    </Location>
```